# How to reduce image quality in Html2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

I want to **reduce image quality** before exporting everything to PDF. If document span more than 3 to 6 pages in PDF, its file size increases heavily(**getting very high quality image**), **~40 MB**. I want reduced file size, something like compressed file. Is there any property that is required to be set in Html2Cavans for compressed file size?

```
html2canvas(form, {
imageTimeout: 2000,
removeContainer: true,
onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var doc = new jsPDF({
        unit: 'pt',
        format: 'a4',
    });

    // pageHeight= doc.internal.pageSize.height;
    var image = new Image();
    image = Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas);
    doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 12, 15);
    var corte = (vm.a4[1] * 1.33333) - 30;
    var croppingYPosition = corte;
    var count = (image.height) / corte;
    for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        doc.addPage();
        var sourceX = 0;
        var sourceY = croppingYPosition;
        var sourceWidth = image.width;
        var sourceHeight = corte;
        var destWidth = sourceWidth;
        var destHeight = sourceHeight;
        var destX = 0;
        var destY = 0;
        var canvas1 = canvas;
        canvas1.setAttribute('height', corte * i);
        canvas1.setAttribute('width', destWidth);
        var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(image, sourceX,
                             sourceY,
                             sourceWidth,
                             sourceHeight,
                             destX,
                             destY,
                             destWidth,
                             destHeight);
        var image2 = new Image();
        image2 = Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas1);
        var image2Data = image2.src;
        doc.addImage(image2Data, 'PNG', 12, 15);
        croppingYPosition += destHeight;
    }
    doc.save('firstPDF.pdf');
    $('.pdfTemplates').css('width', '100%');
}
```

});

Comment: That code snippet as shown just creates the canvas element. How are you getting the image data from it?

Comment: I have updated my query please review it.

Comment: You can only specify the quality for lossy image formats, such as image/jpeg or image/webp – not for PNG. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Comment: So by converting it to JPEG,will I get reduced size? And there is one more problem when I convert it to JPEG. Black background appears in the PDF where there is no data. How to tackle that problem?

Comment: So I guess Html2Canvas transforms the transparent part(where there is no data) into black background. I have found some solutions online, suggesting setting background: #FFFFFF (doesn't work), one solution suggests to change the Script (Html2Canvas) which I doesn't want because it's not always possible. Then what is the proper way of doing it?